# C# memory leak - profiler aid

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I cannot find the specific source of a memory leak caused by a function in a C# WPF application which writes data, in a set of loops, to a SQL DB, via DataContext. I suspect there are objects which are not properly disposed, but I cannot find them.

I tried instantiating a new DataContext within the function to handle all DB interaction, and explicitly calling GC.Collect() at the end of the function. This slows down the memory leak, but does not eliminate it. I've tried using ANTS Memory Profiler, but its snapshots' instance lists & categorizers do not list object names, and simply show a progressively increasing number of generic object instances.

EDIT (and EDIT #2): Suspected memory leak culprit (EDIT 2: w/ called function) -

```
    private void Eq_Get_HistoricalData(String filename, String Symbol)
        {
            List<String[]> fileContents = new List<String[]>();
            List<DailyDataRowObj> data = new List<DailyDataRowObj>();
            DBHandler_Equities DBHE = new DBHandler_Equities();
            ExternalDataHandler EDHP = new ExternalDataHandler();
            Utilities UT = new Utilities();

            if (File.Exists(filename)) {
                fileContents = EDHP.parseCSV(filename);

                for (int i = 1; i < fileContents.Count; i++) {

                    data.Add(Convert_HistoricalCSVRowToDDRO(fileContents[i], Symbol));

                    DBHE.Insert_DailyData_1Day(data[i - 1].Date, Symbol);
                }
                DBHE.Update_DailyData(data);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Eq_Get_HistoricalData: " + Symbol + " file does not exist");
            }

            if (GlobalVar.GlobalDebugDisplay > DebugDisplayLevel.BaseLevel) {
                UT.WriteToTextFile("C:/debug.txt", "Data pull for " + Symbol + " ended: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            }
        }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Separate code snippet, from DBHandler_Equities class definition //

    public void Update_DailyData(List<DailyDataRowObj> DailyDataInput)
    {
        int numRows = DailyDataInput.Count;
        int r = 0;
        using (EquitiesDataContext db = new EquitiesDataContext()) {
            try {
                for (r = 0; r < numRows; r++) {                // loop through PNodeIDs
                    var currRow =                                   // query LMP components for 1 region, 1 hour
                        (from c in db.DailyDatas
                         where c.Symbol == DailyDataInput[r].Symbol
                         && c.Date == DailyDataInput[r].Date
                         select c).First();
                    if (DailyDataInput[r].Price_Close > 0)
                        currRow.Price_Close = DailyDataInput[r].Price_Close;
                    if (DailyDataInput[r].Price_High > 0)
                        currRow.Price_High = DailyDataInput[r].Price_High;
                    if (DailyDataInput[r].Price_Low > 0)
                        currRow.Price_Low = DailyDataInput[r].Price_Low;
                    if (DailyDataInput[r].Price_Open > 0)
                        currRow.Price_Open = DailyDataInput[r].Price_Open;

                    if (DailyDataInput[r].Volume > 0)
                        currRow.Volume = DailyDataInput[r].Volume;

                    if (DailyDataInput[r].Return_Close != 0)
                        currRow.Return_Close = DailyDataInput[r].Return_Close;
                    if (DailyDataInput[r].Return_High != 0)
                        currRow.Return_High = DailyDataInput[r].Return_High;
                    if (DailyDataInput[r].Return_Low != 0)
                        currRow.Return_Low = DailyDataInput[r].Return_Low;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Update_DailyData - DT: " + Convert.ToString(DailyDataInput[r].Date)
                                    + ", Symbol: " + r.ToString() + " - " + e.Message);
            }
            try {
                db.SubmitChanges();
            } catch (Exception) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Update_DailyData - DT: " + Convert.ToString(DailyDataInput[r].Date)
                                    + ", Symbol: " + DailyDataInput[r].Symbol.ToString() + " - db.submitChanges");
            }
            db.Dispose();
        }

        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Note: DBHandler_Equities.Update_DailyData contains DataContext, which is explicitly collected at end.

Comment: It's really hard to say anything without seeing some code, but just to make sure, are you by chance storing EF entity objects in a global list or cache or something that keeps a reference to them? When change tracking is on (it's on by default), all EF entities hold a reference to the entire DataContext and causes it to remain in memory.

Comment: How have you determined that there is infact a memory leak? Ordinary behavior of managed applications can sometimes resemble a memory leak. Many collections only ever increase in size, unless explicitly told to `Trim`; `GC.Collect` is not a `Trim`.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: I don't think I'm using any EF entity objects -- just LINQ objects. I do have a couple custom class objects that I keep essentially global (declared in Form1), just so I can use their member functions without resorting to creating new instances in every function.

Comment: My bad, I think I confused DataContext with ObjectContext...

Comment: @Mr.Smith: ANTS Mem Profiler indicated relatively stable managed memory usage, but much more rapidly growing unmanaged memory usage. I'll look into Trim. Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this article, https://snede.net/hunting-net-memory-leaks-with-windbg/ it shows how to use WinDbg and SOS to Pin-Point to the classes that do not get released